# what is const/type pattern in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-redux

```
export const INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM = 'INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM';
export type INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM = typeof INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM;


export const DECREMENT_ENTHUSIASM = 'DECREMENT_ENTHUSIASM';
export type DECREMENT_ENTHUSIASM = typeof DECREMENT_ENTHUSIASM;
```

what is happening here? I am not able to understand this.It is very confusing
This is from here  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter under **Adding actions** section.

I know what **type** keyword do but it seems very confusing here.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea behind the example you posted is to export both a value and a type so that you'll be able to do something like:

```
let myVar: INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM;
```

If the line:

```
type INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM = typeof INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM
```

was missing the above variable declaration would have raised an error:

> Cannot find name 'DECREMENT_ENTHUSIASM'

Some things in typescript are both a type and a value, suchs as enums and classes, but an interface or a type alias are only types, and in such cases you can then reuse the type name to create a value as well.
For example:

```
type MySingleton = {
    getId(): string;
    doSomething1(str: string): string;
    doSomething2(num: number): number;
}

const MySingleton: MySingleton = {
    getId: function () {
        ...
    },
    doSomething1: function(str: string): string {
        ...
    },
    doSomething2: function (num: number): number {
        ...
    }
}
```

More on types/values in typescript here: [Declaration Merging - Basic Concepts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts)

---

#### Edit

```
type INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM = typeof INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM;
```

Is equal to:

```
type INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM = "INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM";
```

Which makes `INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM` a string that can only be `"INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM"`.

Comment: `type INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM = typeof INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM1` is this means `type INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM = string`

Comment: Check out my revised answer

Comment: but `typeof INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM` returns a string

Comment: In runtime it does, but in compilation time, when the typescript type system is involved, the `typeof INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM` is `"INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM"`. Check it in playground. For example if you have a function: `function fn(a: typeof INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM) { ... }` then you won't be able to call it with: `fn("string")`, you'll get an error: `Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type '"INCREMENT_ENTHUSIASM"'`

Answer (score 8):

By the way, to avoid repeating (and get rid off possible spelling mistakes) I worked out such an idiom:

```
export namespace ShowIdEnum {
  export const ALWAYS = 'always';
  export const LABEL = 'label';
  export const NEVER = 'never';
};
export type ShowIdEnum = typeof ShowIdEnum[keyof typeof ShowIdEnum];
```

Hope it helps ;)